# CSS transform gets overwritten

Tags: jquery, css, transform

I am facing the following problem:

I have 2 functions that apply a css transform to an element (with jquery), without knowing anything from eachother and called at different times.

However they both overwrite eachother.

An example can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cgLy6QXiBNjCcStB9o3j?p=preview). When you click the rotate link, the translate will be overwritten and only the rotation will be applyed. However I would like to keep both transforms.

I assume this is not a jquery bug, but how could I make it work so that they do not overwrite eachother ?

```
box.css({
'-ms-transform': 'translate(50px,100px)', /* IE 9 */
'-webkit-transform': 'translate(50px,100px)', /* Safari */
'transform': 'translate(50px,100px)'
});

rotateIt.on('click', function() {
 box.css({
  '-ms-transform': 'rotate(45deg)', /* IE 9 */
  '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(45deg)', /* Safari */
  'transform': 'rotate(45deg)'
 });
});
```

Comment: You have to combine both the transforms. It is not a CSS or jQuery bug. That is, on click you have to set it like `'transform': 'translate(50px,100px) rotate(45deg)'`.

Comment: I understand thats how I should do it, my problem is that I have 2 independent functions applying those styles. And they have no connection. Is there a workaround in that situation ?

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777489/combine-css3-transforms-via-js) helps. I don't think there is any alternate to getting the current transform value and appending the new transform to it. Or, you could refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30010523/add-a-transform-value-to-the-current-transforms-that-are-already-on-the-element/30010571#30010571) also.

Comment: @RVandersteen Are you saying you can't change the functions? In that case, there's no solution. Give up.

Comment: Well I would like to keep them separate, as they react on different events. I guess I will have to keep the current transform (string) in a variable an append to it before reapplying

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously overwriting the transform property with other if those both classes are of same element.

To use both transform `rotate` and `translate` you can do this

```
 yourSelector{ transform: rotate(45deg) translate(50px,100px); }
```

And in your case try this

```
rotateIt.on('click', function() {
 box.css({
  '-ms-transform': 'rotate(45deg)', /* IE 9 */
  '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(45deg)', /* Safari */
  'transform': 'translate(50px,100px) rotate(45deg)'
 });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but I wonder what would happen if you didn't know what transform was next when you were writing the program.